# Newly created documentation topic and example completely disappears

Tags: support, documentation

About an hour ago, I created a new topic named "Classpath Resources" within the [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java) documentation section. Then I added an example named something like "Finding Resources with Class.getResource()".

After submitting the example for review, I decided to edit it. After editing it, I tried to save it, got an error, and yadda yadda, the topic and example are completely gone. They don't appear in the list of rejected topic requests, or in my drafts, or even the java activity stream.

My first thought was that someone decided the topic was a bad idea and deleted it. In fact I found a previous topic proposal named "Classpath" which was rejected a few months back. If that's the case, I'd expect to get some feedback to that effect, and/or see some remnants in the java activity stream or some other place.

Comment: I just had [a similar experience](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329471/how-do-i-select-at-least-one-draft-to-publish);  does this seem like what happened to you?

Comment: Yes, that sounds similar. (1) Created a topic. (2) Created an example. (3) Edited the example. (4) got an error trying to save the edit. (5) Couldn't find the topic or the example. Unfortunately I don't recall the exact wording of the error.