# New topic and example doesn't show up, message incorrect

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics

I created a new topic under VB.NET, and then added an example, seen in the following image.

[image: You proposed this change to...]

I can't find a link to my proposed topic or change anywhere in the VB.NET documentation page. I have to go into my browser history to find the page. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/34225).

And the text in the screenshot reads:

> You proposed this change to 14 mins ago - editing will retract it.

This change to... what?

The fact that it doesn't appear in requests, and that the text is wrong, leads me to believe that this is a bug.

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328268/newly-created-documentation-topic-and-example-completely-disappears) as well so it appears it's not an isolated event.

**Edit:**

Thanks @animuson for pointing out that the link to this change can be found on the dashboard.

Still, this text is missing something, I assume it's missing the name of the tag, *VB.NET* i.e.

> You proposed this change to *VB.NET* 4 hours ago - editing will retract it.

[image: You proposed this change to... what???]

Answer (score 2):

Your new topic is a proposed change that needs to be reviewed before it is created. It can be seen from the VB.NET dashboard, where other users can look at it and decide to approve or reject the new topic as any other proposed change.

[image: Proposed Changes on Dashboard]

Comment: I see, that wasn't clear to me. For the second half, and what I think is the real bug, it still says *You proposed this change to 4 hours ago - editing will retract it.* specifically this change to what?

Comment: It's supposed to have the topic name, but it doesn't exist yet because your proposed change creates the topic. The word "to" should be removed.