# Documentation: Examples disappeared

Tags: support, documentation, draft

Two days ago I made some examples in the [Mixin-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/3086/mixins) of the ruby language.
But today I don't find them any more.

- For one of them I noted the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/drafts/11401 - it is not found.
- My edit history does not contain my edits.
- I'm sure I saved them, because I switched my computer and continued with my edits on the 2nd computer.
- I'm quite sure I asked for review.
- My problem sounds similar to this one: [Newly created documentation topic and example completely disappears](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328268/newly-created-documentation-topic-and-example-completely-disappears) - but the mixins-topic still extists