# How do I "select at least one draft to publish"?

Tags: support, bug, documentation

I was working on some documentation and started a topic that a user had requested.  I'd written up three examples and then submitted for review.  Then, I realized that I wanted to add a bit more to some of the examples, so I went back and started editing them.  When I select "submit for review" now, I get a red pop up telling me that I "must select at least one draft to publish".  How do I do this?  Clicking the "Save Draft" doesn't appear to require me to select a draft to save.  What am I missing here?

[image: screenshot showing popup]

### Update

Afraid of losing the content that I'd spent a while working on, especially since it no longer appears in my list of drafts,  I created a new topic with the same content, being a bit more careful of the workflow.  After getting the complete content in, I submitted the topic for review and see a few things that add a bit more information:

[image: screenshot of submission confirmation]

- It's not visible to others until it's reviewed.  That's fine, but how do *I* get back to it in the meantime?  It doesn't appear in the list of **all topics**, so I can't browse to it that way, and it's not in my list of drafts.
- Editing will amend the change.  That's probably a nice thing, in that if I edit the submission, the changes would be available to the same reviewer (i.e., it's not going through the review process twice), but if I'm supposed to be able to edit it, how am I supposed to get to it in order to edit it?

Comment: After posting this, I also found a similar question, [Newly created documentation topic and example completely disappears](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328268/newly-created-documentation-topic-and-example-completely-disappears?noredirect=1#comment372888_328268), which might be the same problem.